# importing modules' files into submodules

Tags: python, import, module

i have a module with many files, which i import in themselves for sharing of functionality

```
myModule/
-myFile1.py
-myFile2.py
-mySubmodule/
--myFile3.py
```

i can do `import myFile2`, inside of myFile1, but how can i do a  `import myFile2` in myFile3 without referencing the base module? i dont want to reference myModule, because i am working on a branch so the name is going to change.

Comment: If the name is going to change, why can't you just change it now and get it over with?

Comment: i have two versions of a module and i want to reference them both untill i merge the branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about relative imports. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Within myFile3, you want:

```
from .. import myFile2
```